# how my program stays awake all the time in the background in android studio

Tags: android, background

I am developing a program that like caller id. I have to keep it always awake also runing background.

Which permissions or flags that i need?

Also how can i get permission battery optimizaion close for my app

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for checking/disabling battery optimisation use below methods

```
public static boolean isBatteryOptimisationEnabled(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        return pm != null && !pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context.getPackageName());
    }
    return false;
}

@TargetApi(23)
private static void gotoBatteryOptimisationSettings(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (pm == null || pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
    else {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and for keeping your app running whole the time you have to implement your logic in [`ForegroundService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

Answer (score 0):

You never can keep alive background services for always. if you want to make sure services always keep running you should use foreground service.

**BUT**

for your specific usage, you should use broadcast receivers to observe user calls.[see this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)